# Blender API : pass collection as parameter of python operator

Tags: python, scripting, operator, collections

I am trying to pass a collection as parameter of an operator, but I have following issue :

> AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "collection" from
>   OBJECT_OT_example_op" is read-only

Here is my example code :

```
import bpy

class Item(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Name")

class ExamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "ExamplePanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Example"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("object.example_op", text="Test").collection = bpy.context.scene.collection

class ExampleOperator(bpy.types.Operator): 
    bl_idname = "object.example_op"
    bl_label = "Example Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}   

    collection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=Item)

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        for item in self.collection:
            print(item.name)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Item)
    bpy.types.Scene.collection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=Item)

    it = bpy.context.scene.collection.add()
    it.name = "item1"
    it = bpy.context.scene.collection.add()
    it.name = "item2"   

    bpy.utils.register_class(ExampleOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExamplePanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Any suggestions ?
Tried with PointerProperty, but don't know exactly how to use it, and got same error.

Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure how to pass collection prop to an operator in the layout.  My suggestion is change `for item in self.collection` to `for item in context.scene.collection` ie use the scene collection in the operator.  You can however use `bpy.ops.object.example_op(coll=[{"name":"Goose"}, {"name":"Herman"}])` to pass the collection to the operator... `coll=scene.collection` will throw an error too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use directly context.scene.collection in my case. Will work in this example, but my real case is more complicated, and is not a property of bpy.types.Scene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Campbell give me an answer in Blender mailing list.
Here is the proposed solution :

```
import bpy

class Item(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Name")

class ExamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "ExamplePanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Example"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        op = layout.operator("object.example_op", text="Test")
        for src_item in bpy.context.scene.collection:
            dest_item = op.collection.add()
            dest_item.name = src_item.name


class ExampleOperator(bpy.types.Operator): 
    bl_idname = "object.example_op"
    bl_label = "Example Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}   

    collection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=Item)

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        for item in self.collection:
            print(item.name)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Item)
    bpy.types.Scene.collection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=Item)

    it = bpy.context.scene.collection.add()
    it.name = "item1"
    it = bpy.context.scene.collection.add()
    it.name = "item2"   

    bpy.utils.register_class(ExampleOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExamplePanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: This example should be in the official documentation. Great example.