# Pass collectionProperty through operators (Blender 2.8)

Tags: python, properties, operator

I want to pass some created objects by an operator to another operator for modifications. 
I tested with CollectionProperty, but can't pass the collection from the first operator to the second one:
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  OBJECT_OT_called_op.selItems expected a each sequence member to be a dict for an RNA collection, not SceneSettingItem

What is the problem here ? (Maybe, there is a better method to pass a list of objects).

```
import bpy

# Assign a collection
class SceneSettingItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Test Prop", default="Unknown")



class CallerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """caller"""
    bl_idname = "object.caller_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple caller Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        #Assume we have some selected objects :
        selected = bpy.context.selected_objects

        # Create Collection :
        bpy.types.Scene.my_settings = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)
        # clear collection:
        bpy.context.scene.my_settings.clear()
        # add in collection:
        for obj in selected:
            my_item = bpy.context.scene.my_settings.add()
            my_item.name = obj.name

        # pass collection: 
        bpy.ops.object.called_op(selItems = bpy.context.scene.my_settings)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class CalledOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """called"""
    bl_idname = "object.called_op"
    bl_label = "Called Operator"
    selItems : bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)

    def execute(self, context):
        #read collection
        print ("collection = ",self.selItems)
        for obj in self.selItems:
            print(obj.name)

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CallerOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SceneSettingItem)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CalledOp)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CallerOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SceneSettingItem)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CalledOp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.caller_operator()
```

Comment: Suggest using the operator / context paradigm.  For example by selecting the objects that are created with one operator, they are available to next as `context.selected_objects`  (Note that there is a `context` argument in operator methods so there is no need to use `bpy.context` _ad infinitum_)  If you set the scene property in one operator it is available to the next thru context without passing as argument at all.  Also See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48513/blender-api-pass-collection-as-parameter-of-python-operator

Comment: Thanks batFINGER, context argument was the solution; working code in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to batFINGER's comment, here is the working code: no need to pass arguments here, when calling operator : if it's stored in Scene, we can access to collection through context:

```
import bpy


# Assign a collection
class SceneSettingItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Test Prop", default="Unknown")


class CallerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """calls"""
    bl_idname = "object.caller_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple caller Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Assume we have selected objects :
        selected = context.selected_objects

        # Create Collection :
        bpy.types.Scene.my_settings = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)
        # clear collection:
        context.scene.my_settings.clear()
        # add in collection:
        for obj in selected:
            my_item = context.scene.my_settings.add()
            my_item.name = obj.name

        # call operator: 
        bpy.ops.object.called_op()
        return {'FINISHED'}


class CalledOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """called"""
    bl_idname = "object.called_op"
    bl_label = "Called Operator"
    #selItems : bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)

    def execute(self, context):
        #read collection
        print ("collection = ",context.scene.my_settings)

        for obj in context.scene.my_settings:
            print(obj.name)

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CallerOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SceneSettingItem)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CalledOp)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CallerOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SceneSettingItem)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CalledOp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.caller_operator()
```