# Passing collection property as a parameter to an operator without UI

Tags: python, scripting, operator, custom-properties

I have some automated tests setup for one of my add-ons. However, one of my operators initializes its own collection property parameter upon `invoke()` - which doesn't get called when running an operator from a script. How do I initialize and set the collection property parameters for a given execution?

Here is example code, derivative of [Blender API : pass collection as parameter of python operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48513/blender-api-pass-collection-as-parameter-of-python-operator):

```py
import bpy

class Item(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    is_true: bpy.props.BoolProperty()

class ExampleOperator(bpy.types.Operator): 
    bl_idname = "object.example_op"
    bl_label = "Example Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}   

    collection: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=Item)

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        for item in self.collection:
            print(item.name, item.is_true)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Item) 
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExampleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Any suggestions ? Tried with PointerProperty, but don't know exactly how to use it, and got same error. Thanks :)

Comment: FWIW you can execute the invoke method of an operator from code with `bpy.ops.object.example_op("INVOKE_DEFAULT")` see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html

Comment: True, you can. In my case, I wanted to change the default values in the collection properties to test different situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a dict which the operator will use to initialize the collection parameter. Here's how I called the operator in my script:

```py
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.example_op(
    collection=[{'name': 'first_key', 'is_true': True},  {'name': 'second_key', 'is_true': False}]
)
```

Comment: Wow this is a very hidden, obscure and awesome feature !! May I ask where you found this information ? I don't remember seeing this anywhere in the docs or else. Trial and error ?

Comment: From this comment by batFINGER: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48513/blender-api-pass-collection-as-parameter-of-python-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment82538_48513
It didn't end up being what the user wanted, but it saved me time.